# how can I launch Differernt URL in different elevated button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

want to launch URL in ELEVATEDBUTTON. there are too many button for launch too many URL how can I do this in flutter??

I can't understand how can I do this. can anyone solve this problem

Comment: can you include your snippet that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

you can map the list while rendering on ui.

```dart
...urlList
    .map(
      (e) => ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          launchUrl(Uri.parse(e)); //use .tryParse 
        },
        child: Text("$e"),
      ),
    )
    .toList(),
```

You may create a model class with label and string url.

Comment: can you please explain brifly with example

Comment: `urlList` is a list of string that contains URL as string.  I am using spread operator(...), you can remove if it is just needed on single column.  What else didn't you get here?